# basic laravel route with other pages

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am making a blog in laravel. I set slug after my base url:

```
Route::get('/{slug}',['as'=>'blog.single','uses'=>'blogController@getSingle'])
    ->where('slug','[\w\d-\_]+');
```

the problem is I want to open admin panel like this:

> www.mydomainname.com/admin

but whenever I write admin the above route call and my app understand admin is also a slug, same case with other pages like contact us and about us and any others. I want to open pages like this:

> www.mydomainname.com/contact
>   www.mydomainname.com/abouts-us

and I want to open slugs like this:

> www.mydomainname.com/my-slug

Answer (score 3):

Try moving the declaration of your admin route above the route looking for a slug:

```
Route::get('/admin', ['as'=>'admin.index', 'uses' => 'AdminController@index']);
Route::get('/{slug}',['as'=>'blog.single','uses'=>'blogController@getSingle'])
    ->where('slug','[\w\d-\_]+');
```

In general it would be a good idea to keep your `{slug}` route at the very end of your routes file to prevent it 'stomping' on your other routes.